# C++ 14 main function's form

Tags: c++11, return

I saw this code. Can you explain me, whats mean this piece of code:

```
  auto main() ->
    {

    }
```

What is difference between this and follow code:

```
int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that the exact code? Can you provide a reference to where you saw that?

Comment: The first snippet is not valid C++Whenever code. If you meant `auto main() -> int`, then yes, that would be valid and just look different.

Answer (score 4):

`auto main()` is illegal in as per the resolution of [core issue 1669](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1669).

The intent of whatever person gave you that code was probably to use return type deduction to figure out the return type.  This happens in C++11 lambdas, and is being extended to most functions (`main` being one exception) in C++14.